# How do I refresh UIWebview for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have an iPhone app that has a UIWebView.  After X hours and the user launches the app again, I'm finding the webview is showing the same data even though the page might have new content.  How do I automatically get the UIWebView to refresh the page when the user launches the app for a second time after X hours?

Answer (score 2):

For reloading the webView use

```
[webView reload];
```

For calculating time difference:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

For counting X hours do this:

Add this is viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnteredBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationEnteredForeground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Write notification handling functions

```
 -(void)applicationEnteredBackground
 {
  //storing timestamp when user goes background 
  NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
  [userDefaults synchronize];    
 }

 -(void)applicationEnteredForeground
 {
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *lastTimeOpened= [userDefaults objectForKey:@"timeStamp"];
   NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   //set formatter style as long
   if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[formatter dateFromString:lastTimeOpened]] > X hours)
   {
     //reload your webview here.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hey there can be a small logic error but this is how you do it, please get back to me.

Comment: @sharataka Did it work? Accept, up vote my ans if you are cool with it.